# split column values into separate rows (pivot)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
App    Downloads    Permissions
A      123          56
B      89           12
```

I want to modify the `df`to look like like this:

```
App    Title              Value    
A      Downloads          123
A      Permissions        56
B      Downloads          89
B      Permissions        12
```

How can I achieve this? I have looked into the pivot_table functions but it seems a bit different than what I am trying to achieve. Also, not sure how to add the names (Title/Value) for the new columns I want to create

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `melt` to get these results

```
df.melt(value_vars = ['Downloads', 'Permissions'])
```